# How to user Assert for methods with return type void in MSTest

Tags: c#, task, mstest, void

I have a method in my c# application similar to below.

```
public async Task SampleMethod()
{
    try
    {
        //some code 
        await AnotherMethod();
        // some code
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());        
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to write a unit testcase for the above method using MStest. I have written something as below.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task SampleMethodTest()
{
    ClassName cn = new ClassName();
    await cn.SampleMethod();
 }
```

Now how do I know if the testcase failed or succeeded. How do I use Assert here?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to test?

Comment: @Sakuto I want to test SampleMethod()

Comment: Yeah but whichj behavior in your method? You do not have any return, nor condition. What's the logical path you want to test?

Comment: @Sakuto In SampleMethod() , I have not mentioned any code here, but there are some conditions and loops which are to be tested. The only concern I have is, since it is not returning any value, how would I know if the method is failed.Is it mandatory for me to return some value to test a method? Or is there any other way?

Comment: It depends on how the condition affect the flow of your method. For example, if one of the condition throw an exception, you can just test that if a given parameter, it will throw this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our comments in my other answer, i try to show you how to get the console output. That you can read all text from console you have to set a StringWriter() to the console:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task SampleMethodTest()
{
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        Console.SetOut(stringWriter);

        ClassName cn = new ClassName();
        await cn.SampleMethod();

        string consoleOutput = stringWriter.ToString();

        Assert.IsFalse(consoleOutput.Contains("Exception"));
    }
}
```

I hope this works. I haven't tried it with a UnitTest, only with a console program.

Answer (score 0):

If you test the AnotherMethod directly, you will see if it's succefull. When it throws an Exception the test is failed. The SampleMethod does only implement the try catch and calls the AnotherMethod() which can be tested directly.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task SampleMethodTest()
{
   ClassName cn = new ClassName();
   await cn.AnotherMethod();
 }
```

This test fail if it throws an Execption. When the method do not throw an Exception, it is successfull.

Comment: Thanks for replying. If a method is returning true or false, then in the test method we write Asset.IsTrue(returnvalue) . Since SampleMethod() is not returning anything, what will I write in Assert?

Comment: You don't have to use a Assert. Test AnotherMethod() and if this method throw an exception, then the Test fails. If not the Test is successfull. When AnotherMethod() run successfully, the SampleMethod() would be also successfull.

Comment: The reason you can't test the SampleMethod() is, that it hasn't a return type and you handle the exception and never throw. So the method is succefull everytime you execute it. Because of that you should test the AnotherMethod() directly.

Comment: I completely understand what you said. But I need to write testcases for every method in order to increase the code coverage.

Comment: So you can take the console output and check it. Check it with something like this: Assert.IsFalse(consoleOutput.Contains("Exception")).

Comment: This seems to be good solution to solve my issue. But I copied the line which you have given, it is giving an error saying "The name consoleOuput doesn't exist in the current context".

Answer (score 0):

If your method changes the state of the object, you can verify if the state of the object is like expected. If not you can use a Mock (with a Framework like Moq) to verify the collaboration with other objects. Note that you maybe need to extract AnotherMethod to another class, so that you can mock and verify the call.

Also note that you should try to design your Software so that you can use Outputverification and Stateverification in most UnitTests. Communication Verification with mocks can lead to false postives and UnitTests that are hard to maintain.