How to get console output in VSCode unit tests on Ubuntu
I have used both Console.WriteLine(...) and Debug.WriteLine(...) in my MSTest unit tests and I have no output on any terminal/console tabs in VSCode.
How do I get write/log to the Output Console or Terminal?
    [TestMethod]
    public void InstantiateIndex()
    {
        var index = new Index(segment1);

        Assert.AreEqual(text, index.ToString());
        Assert.AreEqual(text.Length, index.Length);

        Debug.WriteLine($"text: '{index}'");
    }

Test otherwise passes but no output. Tried Console.WriteLine as well.

unit tests are not debugging

Is that why the downvote? Could have just correct the tag, my goodness.

i don't know why you was downvoted but the clode vote , is because of lack of detail, we can't say what is wrong as you didn't provide your test, as i use it in visual studio, i don't know if i can help but you need to tell us exactly what you are doing

And I disagree with your initial statement.That unit tests are not debugging when one fails.You debug, you have output statements and you check values etc. So I disagree with your initial premise.

Visual studio (non code) has a setting to hide the output of passing tests, maybe code does too? If you make a test failure after the write line does the message show?

Why are you trying to output to STDOUT for a unit test? Unit test runners typically don't work like that. If you really need to get something out, maybe a temporary logging file?

or something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52438786/5193536

@IAbstract  debugging and unit tests still are different, unit tests can point  you in the right direction(failed) but before youi write unit tests you should intensely debug your code

probably best to stick to the objective nature of the question rather than the philosophies of development ... ;) ... and for the other comment on "why?" (@gunr2171) ... because I want to.
